# Yahoo Pipes: How to convert string from Fetch Page into date for RSS feed?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I am trying to create a rss feed from a web page.  I am able to get the data to create the title, but I am trying to get the date updated correctly.  There is a string on the page, that tells what time of day the news was reported, such as "Time of Report: 1pm".  So how can I get the "1pm" and convert that to a date string that contains the current date, with this time?
Thanks,
CP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pipes "Date Builder" module is surprisingly powerful.

You can actually feed it a string like "1pm" and it will return:

```
hour21
timezoneUTC
second0
month1
minute0
utime1264021200
day20
day_of_week3
year2010
```

The date is relative to when you run it - in this case it assumes "1pm Today". The result is "hour21" in UTC because it parsed in Yahoo's time-zone. So if you need something specific, use the "Sting Builder" to append the time-zone. For example "1pm GMT" gives:

```
hour13
timezoneUTC
second0
month1
minute0
utime1263992400
day20
day_of_week3
year2010
```

Obviously you may run into issues if your pipe runs after a date change - an "11pm" entry could easily be read the following morning, leading to inaccurate results.

Comment: Ok that is close, but how do I get the text from an item and pipe it to the data builder input?

Comment: Ok I half figured it out using a Loop, with a Date Builder inside.